# Unable to connect to IBM DB2 from SSIS / VS.NET 2015, though works with VS.NET 2013

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2015, odbc

We are planning to upgrade from SQL Server 2014 and Visual Studio 2013 to SQL Server 2016 and Visual Studio 2015.

The error message:
[IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Communication link failure. 
comm rc=25202 - CWBCO1034 - SSL error, function  returned 25202

Background

We have an SSIS project which connects to an IBM DB2 server and retrieves data. This has been working for years.
The working setup looks like this:
Windows 10

Visual Studio 2013

SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013

IBM i Access for Windows, version 7 Release 1

A DSN pointing to the IBM DB2 server

ADO.NET Connection Manager with ODBC Data Provider pointing to the DSN mentioned above.

SSL enabled on the DSN.

If we on the same machine use Visual Studio 2015 and subsequently SQL Server Data Tools 2015, it no longer works. Everything else is the same!

As soon as the package is opened and SSIS starts to validate the connection managers the error message arises.